# Can you add a system stored proc to Entity framework data model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Can I add a system SP like sp_executesql to EF4 data model?

although I can see some of the system sps in the list but not the sp_executesql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_executesql` is extended system stored procedure defined in `Master` database in `sys` schema. By simply connecting entity model to `Master` database I guess that it automatically filters everything from `sys` schema.

You don't need `sp_executesql` in entity framework - use `ExecuteStoreCommand` method of `ObjectContext` instance instead.

Comment: will I be able to define the output type if I use ExecuteStoreCommand? just like when I used a SP which doesn't has select statement(something dynamic) I am still able to specify the output type.

Comment: ExecuteStoreQuery is the answer for my question in Comment. Amazing!! Thanks.